# Show message from Server in Angular2

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am trying send object to my Angular2 but I can't receive the message:

I create a class in my Server SpringBoot:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class MyMessage {

    boolean success;
    String message;

    public MyMessage(boolean success,String message){
        this.success = success;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

I created a object

```
        boolean result = pgRepository.createParam(parameter);
        String message;

        if(result) message =   "Insertado con éxito";
        else message = "Hubo un problema al insertar";

        return new MyMessage(result , message);
```

Finally In my Angular I receive the answer:

```
             this.service.addConfig(url, newConfig).subscribe(param => {

              this.myMessage.success = param['success'];
              this.myMessage.message = param['message'];

                console.log('all' , param);
                console.log('message index 0' , param[1]);
                console.log('message' , param['message']);
```

[image]

I need get 'message' from Server but I get `"` or `undefined`

Comment: can you add a `console.log(param);` and add the ouput to the question?

Comment: Why dont you use `console.log(param.message)` directly?

Comment: console.log('all' , param); I show in the img ... please, check the IMG

Comment: I think that param is all to String, but I need the boolean and String

Comment: Do you get the same result when you access the properties like this.
`param.message` and `param.success` ?

Comment: param.success or param.message Property 'message' no existe en el tipo 'string'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the `param` as string and not `Json`.
use `JSON.parse(param)` to convert into json and then use it

Comment: @EduBw Please verify your `content-type` in web service